# Deseo obtener las 3 primeros caracteres de una frase en PHP

Tags: php

No se si es posible obtener los 3 primeros carácteres de una frase solo con php

```
$nombre = 'Carlos jurado ames';

$separadas = ((substr($nombre,0,1)).(substr($nombre,1,2)).(substr($nombre,2,3)));
```

No se como hacerlo solo utilizando php y obtener `'cja'`,

O talvez necesito hacer una función, no lo tengo muy claro no se si alguien pueda ayudarme

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero que tienes que hacer, es utilizar el método `explode()` para separar tu frase en las palabras.

Luego con el método `substr()`, utilizándola en cada una de las palabras, para coger la primera letra, y guardarla en la variable. Con un `foreach()` por ejemplo podrás recorrer el array devuelto por el método `explode()`, y dentro de este hacer que se guarde la letra en una cadena, donde sumas una letra cada vez.

Por lo que tu `PHP` deberá de ser así:

```
<?php
$nombre = 'Carlos jurado ames';
$separadas = explode(" ", $nombre);
$corto = "";
foreach ($separadas as $primera) {
    $corto .= substr($primera, 0, 1);
}
?>
```

Puedes imprimir el valor de `$corto`, y te imprimirá lo que buscas:

> Cja

Comment: Gracias voy a probarlo

Answer (score 1):

No estoy seguro si quieres solo los 3 primeros caracteres o bien todos los primeros caracteres de cada palabra de una frase en minúsculas.  Mi respuesta se aplica en este segundo caso:

```php
$nombre = 'Carlos jurado ames';
$resultado = mb_strtolower(preg_replace(['/(\w)\w+/','/\s/'],['${1}',''], $nombre));
echo $resultado;  // devuelve cja
```

### Explicación

Aprovechando que [preg_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php) acepta matrices de sustitución realizamos dos búsquedas con sustitución sobre el string **$nombre**, a saber:

```
preg_replace(['/(\w)\w+/','/\s/'],['${1}',''], $nombre)
```

1. En la primera buscamos la expresión regular `'/(\w)\w+/'` que significa:

```
(               # paréntesis que indica que será un parámetro
 \w             # busca el primer caracter de palabra (equivale a [a-zA-Z0-9_])
)               # cerramos el parámetro
\w+             # busca el resto de caracteres contiguos que desecharemos
```

y eso lo sustituimos por:

```
${1}            # es el primer parámetro de la expresión regular entre paréntesis
                # en este caso se corresponde con el primer carácter de cada palabra
```

Ésta primera sustitución nos generará un resultado de `C j a` al cual ahora queremos eliminar sus espacios, y de ahí la segunda búsqueda:

2. Buscamos los espacios en el resultado anterior mediante esta sintaxis:

```
\s
```

y los reemplazamos por nada, `''`, es decir, los eliminamos, y de este modo la cadena resultante de ambas operaciones ahora es `Cja`.

3. Pero tal como parece indicarse en la pregunta, se pretende que el resultado sea `cja`, en minúsculas, por lo tanto aplicamos sobre ese resultado la funcion [mb_strtolower()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mb-strtolower.php) que realizará la conversión obteniendo al final el resultado esperado:

```
cja
```

Answer (score 0):

primero tienes que separar las frases en distintas variables o en un arreglo.

```
$nombre  = "Carlos jurado ames";
```

Divides el string de nombre de personas por los espacios

```
$palabrasSeparadas = explode(" ", $nombre);
```

Luego tal cual como lo hiciste en tu pregunta, debes buscar el primer carácter de la cadena.

```
$c = substr($palabrasSeparadas[0],0,1); // Carlos - C
$j = substr($palabrasSeparadas[1],0,1);// jurado - j
$a = substr($palabrasSeparadas[2],0,1); // ames - a
```

Finalmente solo queda unirlo

```
$resultadoEsperado = c.j.a;
```

Disculpa si hay algun error de sintaxis, ya que no programo en php, fui buscando codigo en internet

Comment: Gracias... Por tu ayuda voy a probarlo

Comment: En caso de que cambie la variable `$nombre`, y en vez de tener una frase de tres palabras, tenga una de más, o de menos, esto dejará de funcionar

Comment: @Maidagan Claro, la mejor forma de hacerlo en con un foreach como lo hiciste tú, te permite jugar con la cantidad de palabras que quieras.